# Procedure is not running

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am running below query, giving error. what needs to be done to get the requested result?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE data_cleanup_29th_nov_2020
IS
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC as select JOB_ID, last_update_time_utc, status from J_DOC where 
LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30 and status=''Sent''';

  execute immediate 'delete from HUB_SIG where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC)';

 execute immediate 'delete from J_DOC 
 where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC)';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'RENAME TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';

END;

commit;
```

After running the procedure getting below error

```
BEGIN
  data_cleanup_29th_nov_2020();
--rollback; 
END;
```

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
> ORA-06512: at "HUB.DATA_CLEANUP_29TH_NOV_2020", line 7
> ORA-06512: at line 2
> 00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object

Tried with below query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ATAS_CLEANUP_NOV_2020 IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC as select JOB_ID, last_update_time_utc, status from J_DOC where 
LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30 and status=''Sent''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from HUB_SIGNATURE_DETAILS where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC)';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from J_DOC
 where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC)';

    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'RENAME TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHER THEN
            NULL;
    END;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC RENAME TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
END;
```

Getting below error:

> Error(14,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> Error(17,14): PLS-00201: identifier 'OTHER' must be declared

Tried with this and it works successfully:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ATAS_LATEST_DATA_cleanup_nov IS
BEGIN


    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from HUB_SIG where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC)';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from J_DOC 
 where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC)';

    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'RENAME TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
   --BEGIN
     -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
    --EXCEPTION
      --  WHEN OTHER THEN
        --   NULL;
   -- END;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC RENAME TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
END;

COMMIT;

BEGIN
  ATAS_LATEST_DATA_cleanup_nov();
--rollback; 
END;
```

anonymous block completed

Created the temporary table outside the procedure.
create table TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119 as select JOB_ID, last_update_time_utc, status from J_DOC where
LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30 and status='Sent'

And used the temporary table inside procedure now after procedure run data is present in TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119

Now we have to implement to  get the date as input and pass that
when  rename the table (RENAME TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119 )

and schedule this procedure in DBMS_SCHEDULER to run every night at 10 PM PST.
How can we do this?

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, you can’t create a table with a particular name as one already exists. Perhaps you want to use a different table name, perhaps you want to insert into the existing table without creating it first? As a general thought, this sort of thing looks like it wouldn’t need any of this dynamic sql if you inserted the rows into a (permenant) global temporary table then archived them at the end into a regular table.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Because the table doesn't (or shouldn't) exist until the procedure has been run so if you don't use `EXECUTE IMMEDITATE` then it would fail at compile time from the non-existent table.

Comment: This won't work after the first time because it refers to a table named TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC which it renames to TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119 at the end. The second time you run it, it'll fail because there is no TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rename table` command is wrong.

It should be:

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC RENAME TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119;
```

Also, you can execute the procedure once, If you will execute it again then it will throw an error at the rename command.

Now, See if there is any table available in the DB already. If yes, then remove it before calling the following procedure again.

So try this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATA_CLEANUP_29TH_NOV_2020
(P_IN_DATE IN DATE)
IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC as select JOB_ID, last_update_time_utc, status from J_DOC where 
LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30 and status=''Sent''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from HUB_SIG where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC)';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from J_DOC 
 where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC)';

    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'RENAME TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHER THEN
            NULL;
    END;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC RENAME TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_' || TO_CHAR(P_IN_DATE, 'MMYY');
END;
/
```

It is always good practice to avoid dynamic queries.

You can create one table outside of this procedure and use it to store temporary data. Or you can use the Global temporary table.

Comment: We need to  automate them inside procedure. we  must get the date as input and pass that
 when  rename the table (RENAME TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119 ) 

and schedule this procedure in DBMS_SCHEDULER

Comment: You can also use `rename t1 to t2;` (though not `rename table t1 to t2` as the OP tried initially).

Comment: `when others` is missing an `s`.

Comment: I have executed the procedure now now we need date as input and pass that when rename the table (RENAME TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC TO TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_JOB_DOC_1119 ) and schedule this procedure in DBMS_SCHEDULER

Comment: "we must get the date as input and pass that when rename the table"  Then I would suggest your data model is fundamentally flawed.  A date is inherently a bit of business data, and that should NOT be incorporated into the names of objects - tables or procedure names.

Comment: Thanks Tejash,  my date is format like: 128804077 20-AUG-19 04.19.15.450803000 AM Sent
128804077 20-AUG-19 04.19.15.450803000 AM Sent
94659820 20-AUG-19 04.19.15.450803000 AM Sent  in this above procedure how to run and pass it, and how to put in dbms scheduler.

Comment: the date has no format in oracle. It is just shown to you using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. In the above example, You don't need to pass the string but the date. If you want to call your procedure then use `DATA_CLEANUP_29TH_NOV_2020(date_variable)`

Comment: I need to delete records older then 90 days from procedure, so can i put the date like to execute the procedure to delete records older then 90 days...should ask input like how many days older records need to delete. also need to schedule in scheduler.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. I think your original question is resolved. You should ask new question and mark this/relevant answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Please check " create table TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC " this create table statement because "TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC " is already exist in your system.